# HealthKit - Get Blood Glucose Meal Time

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

When adding a new blood glucose reading, it's possible to choose Meal Time for the reading. There's picker with three values (Unspecified, Before Meal, After Meal).

I was able to successfully get the reading using:

```
HKQuantitySample sample = ...
var value = sample.quantity.GetDoubleValue(hkUnit);
```

But I've no idea how to get the mealtime.

How can I get the meal time using HealthKit Query?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get it through the metadata property):

```
let mealtime = sample.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyBloodGlucoseMealTime] as? Int
```